# How to pass lambda as parameter in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, lambda

I have a big function in Javascript that I need to repeat the same logic, except for the line bellow, that is different:

```
config.some(x => x.site === text)
```

The other function will do the same thing, but instead of filtering by SITE, it will filter by NAME:

```
config.some(x => x.name === text)
```

I want to pass SITE or NAME as a parameter to the method. How can I do this?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
myMethod(lambda) {
   config.some(lambda === text)
}
```

And call like:

```
this.myMethod(x => x.site);
```

Comment: `myMethod(lambda) { return config.some(x => lambda(x) === text); }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass the parameter name it could be done like this:

```
myMethod(key) {
   config.some(x => x[key] === text)
}
myMethod('name');
```

A "lambda" passing implementation would look like:

```
myMethod(lambda) {
   config.some(x => lambda(x) === text)
}
const nameLambda = (x) => x.name;
myMethod(nameLambda);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error: "x is not defined". Can you please review this line?
config.some(x[key] === text)

Comment: I don't know where your `x` is, you used it in your example as if it were defined there.

Comment: Ah got it! Then I should do this: config.some(x => x[key] === text).
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the lambda argument directly to the `some` function. 
Here is an example with filter.

```js
function methodWithLambda(lambda) {
  let data = [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  ]
  
  return data.filter(lambda);
}

console.log(methodWithLambda(x => x > 4));
console.log(methodWithLambda(x => x < 7));
```